# How to add the external libirary in the OMNET++ 5.6.2

Tags: c++, cmake, omnet++, ipfs

I'm using Windows 11, in OMNET++. I tried to include the ipfs library for c++, and I have two questions:

1. I don't know where to add the "include" and "lib" directories in OMNET++, just like what this guy did [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j13iYc6zRuk). All I can find on the internet is let me do this in Project >> project features >> Makemake >> Options >> Link, which I don't really get it.
2. I don't really know which specific file should it be in the CURL_LIBRARY and CURL_INCLUDE_DIR, and how to impletemented it in my `CMakeLists.txt`

In OMNET++ I coded this:

```
#include <ipfs/client.h>
```

but it shows

> unresolved inclusion

So I downloaded the library from [github](https://github.com/vasild/cpp-ipfs-http-client), created a "build" directory and used
`cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

It completed but I got a lot of warnings like:

```
C:\LIBRARIES\cpp-ipfs-http-client\build>cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found CURL: C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib (found version "7.88.1")
-- Fetching nlohmann/JSON
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1282 (message):
  The DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option was not given and policy CMP0135 is
  not set.  The policy's OLD behavior will be used.  When using a URL
  download, the timestamps of extracted files should preferably be that of
  the time of extraction, otherwise code that depends on the extracted
  contents might not be rebuilt if the URL changes.  The OLD behavior
  preserves the timestamps from the archive instead, but this is usually not
  what you want.  Update your project to the NEW behavior or specify the
  DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option with a value of true to avoid this
  robustness issue.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:68 (FetchContent_Declare)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Using the single-header code from C:/LIBRARIES/cpp-ipfs-http-client/build/_deps/json-src/single_include/
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - no
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done (13.5s)
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "ipfs-http-client" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_block" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_config" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_dht" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_files" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_generic" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_key" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_name" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_object" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_pin" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_stats" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_swarm" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:80 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "test_threading" requests linking to directory
  "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
  is dropping the item.


-- Generating done (1.5s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/LIBRARIES/cpp-ipfs-http-client/build
```

My CMakeLists.txt in cpp-ipfs-http-client folder is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.0)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe")
set(CURL_LIBRARY "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/lib")
set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/LIBRARIES/curl-7.88.1/include")


# Adhere the version number to http://semver.org/
project(cpp-ipfs-http-client VERSION 0.6.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

# Compile in C++11 mode
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Add compiler warnings
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "^(AppleClang|Clang|GNU)$")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror")
endif()

# Generate compile_commands.json, to be used by YouCompleteMe.
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# Set the available options 
option(DOC "Build Doxygen" OFF)
option(COVERAGE "Enable generation of coverage info" OFF)
option(BUILD_TESTING "Enable building test cases" ON)

# Find curl
# Look for static import symbols for Windows builds
if(WIN32)
    add_definitions("-DCURL_STATICLIB")
endif()
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

# When build with coverage, set the correct compiler flags before the targets are defined
if(COVERAGE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

  include(CodeCoverage)
  append_coverage_compiler_flags()
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O0")
endif()

# Targets
set(IPFS_API_LIBNAME ipfs-http-client)

# To build and install a shared library: "cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON ..."
add_library(${IPFS_API_LIBNAME}
  src/client.cc
  src/http/transport-curl.cc
)

# Add include directories
target_include_directories(${IPFS_API_LIBNAME}
  PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# Fetch "JSON for Modern C++"
include(FetchContent)
message(STATUS "Fetching nlohmann/JSON")
# Retrieve Nlohmann JSON
FetchContent_Declare(json URL https://github.com/nlohmann/json/releases/download/v3.10.5/json.tar.xz)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(json)

# libcurl requires additional libs only for static Windows builds
if(WIN32)
   set(WINDOWS_CURL_LIBS idn2 unistring iconv charset ssh2 gcrypt gpg-error ws2_32 advapi32 crypt32 wldap32)
endif()

set_target_properties(${IPFS_API_LIBNAME} PROPERTIES
  SOVERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}
  VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
)
target_link_libraries(${IPFS_API_LIBNAME} ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${WINDOWS_CURL_LIBS} nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
if(NOT DISABLE_INSTALL)
  install(TARGETS ${IPFS_API_LIBNAME} DESTINATION lib)
  install(FILES include/ipfs/client.h DESTINATION include/ipfs)
  install(FILES include/ipfs/http/transport.h DESTINATION include/ipfs/http)
  install(FILES ${json_SOURCE_DIR}/include/nlohmann/json.hpp DESTINATION include/nlohmann)
endif()
# Tests, use "CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 make test" to see output from failed tests

# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CTest.html
include(CTest)
if(BUILD_TESTING)
  add_subdirectory(test)
endif()

if(DOC)
  include(doxygen)
endif()
```

If I solve the warnings, what should I do next for generating the lib folder (if needed, based on the first question).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your library is in the following directories:

- `C:\foo\lib` contains library files (e.g. `libipfs.a` or `libipfs.dll`)
- `C:\foo\include` contains headers (i.e. `ipfs\client.h`)

To add own libraries to an existing `OMNeT++` project go to `Project` | `Properties` | `OMNeT++` | `Makemeke` | select root or src directory | `Options`, then `Custom` | `Makefrag` and write the following lines:

```
EXTRA_OBJS += -LC:/foo/lib -lipfs
CFLAGS += -IC:/foo/include
```

Comment: Thank you. And do you know why I don't have a library file in my build folder after using cmake command, I've searched for .lib .a .dll .so, but none of them has been found.  I am not using Visual Studio CMake by the way, is it different between MinGW and Visual Studio?

Comment: There is the rule in SO that one question is devoted to one (and only one) problem. I have answered for the issue of adding path to libraries. So I suggest [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75738042/edit) your question and removing the part of building ipfs library. Then create a new question for problems with building ipfs library.